# How could i run this command as a root?

Tags: 14.04

```
 mohamed@MoHy:~$ airmon-ng
     Run it as root
```

so how could i run this command as a root ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can precede the command with

```
sudo
```

**Edited after Chris pointed out**

This way you will be prompted to enter your password (once you are allowed to execute commands as super user). And then you'll execute as super user.

Try [this](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_sudo.htm) for more info.

Or even open the terminal and type

```
man sudo
```

Comment: You can also start the terminal with                                                                            `su`                                                                                                                                              and then make commands from there.

Comment: Just to clarify... You have to enter your password, not root password.

Comment: @Chris, good point.

Answer (score 1):

Write

```
sudo airmon-ng
```

instead of just

```
airmon-ng
```